# Pandas return DataFrame from apply function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
sdf = sdf['Name1'].apply(lambda x: tryLookup(x, tdf))
```

`tryLookup` is a function that is currently taking a string, which is the value of `Name1` in the sdf column. We map the function using apply to every row in the `sdf` DataFrame.

Instead of `tryLookup` returning just a string, is there a way for `tryLookup` to return a DataFrame that I want to merge with the `sdf` DataFrame? `tryLookup` has some extra information, and I want to include that in the results by adding them as new columns to all the rows in `sdf`.

So the return for `tryLookup` is as such:

```
return pd.Series({'BEST MATCH': bestMatch, 'SIMILARITY SCORE': humanScore})
```

I tried something such as

```
sdf = sdf.merge(sdf['Name1'].apply(lambda x: tryLookup(x, tdf)), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But that just throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lookup.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "lookup.py", line 40, in main
    sdf = sdf.merge(sdf['Name1'].apply(lambda x: tryLookup(x, tdf)), left_index=True, right_index=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4618, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 58, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 473, in __init__
    'type {0}'.format(type(right)))
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `pd.lookup`?https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the pd.Series to a dataframe with `pandas.Series.to_frame` as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
sdf = sdf.merge(sdf['Sold To Name (10)'].apply(lambda x: tryLookup(x, tdf)).to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: `sdf` is a DataFrame in this case.